# Scrambles radio button data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a little problem about doing data randomization. I am currently making an online exam system, where the sequence of questions will be random and the order of answers will also be random. But now I can only randomize the question just with the Sql query using "order by random". but for the choice of answers I still can't randomize it, is there anything that can help me?

this my results 
[image]

```
        my script

$html .= $d->soal.'<br>'.$tampil_media.'<div class="funkyradio">';

                        for ($j = 0; $j < $this->config->item('jml_opsi'); $j++) {
                            $opsi = "opsi_".$this->opsi[$j];
                            $checked = $arr_jawab[$d->id]["j"] == strtoupper($this->opsi[$j]) ? "checked" : "";
                            $pc_pilihan_opsi = explode("#####", $d->$opsi);

                            $tampil_media_opsi = (is_file('./upload/gambar_soal/'.$pc_pilihan_opsi[0]) || $pc_pilihan_opsi[0] != "") ? tampil_media('./upload/gambar_opsi/'.$pc_pilihan_opsi[0],'auto','auto') : '';

                            $pilihan_opsi = empty($pc_pilihan_opsi[1]) ? "-" : $pc_pilihan_opsi[1];

                            $html .= 
                            '<div class="funkyradio-success" onclick="return simpan_sementara();">
                            <fieldset class="radio">
                            <span class="text-primary">'.$this->opsi[$j].'.</span>
                            <input type="radio" id="opsi_'.strtoupper($this->opsi[$j]).'_'.$d->id.'" name="opsi_'.$no.'" value="'.strtoupper($this->opsi[$j]).'" '.$checked.'> 
                            <label for="opsi_'.strtoupper($this->opsi[$j]).'_'.$d->id.'">'.$pilihan_opsi.$tampil_media_opsi.'</label> 
                            </fieldset>
                            </div>';
                        }
                        $html .= '</div></div>';
                        $no++;
```

table sql
[image]

Comment: You can randomize it on the front end ... Share your generated html by your php

Comment: If you want to randomize it from your PHP code implement Fisher-Yates randomization: use a random number generator to randomly select an item from your array, then remove it from the original as you push it onto a new array; repeat for the rest of the items in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answers appear to be indexed numerically, you could randomise them by creating an array of index values and shuffling that, and then looping over those values. So replace this `for` statement:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $this->config->item('jml_opsi'); $j++) {
```

with:

```
$indexes = range(0, $this->config->item('jml_opsi') - 1);
shuffle($indexes);
foreach ($indexes as $j) {
```

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/L6ocl) of the result of the shuffling code on 3v4l.org.